# How to Detect Flip of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer

is there a logic to detect if the user has flipped their phone like from battery side to screen side and vice versa in horizontal plane? I have tried getting raw values to determine if the device is in the horizontal position on both faces but how to detect the whole motion , could someone point me in right direction.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the [UIDevice class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDeviceOrientation), you'll see the orientation enum. Two of it's values are `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp`. That being said, all you have to do is register an observer to the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification, and upon call you can check the devices current orientation and handle this accordingly.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown) {
        // device facing down
    }else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp) {
        // device facing up
    }else{
        // facing some other direction
    }
}];
```

Be sure to use the following to start generating the device notifications you'll need to observe.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

If you want to get more specific information about the orientation of the device, you'll need to use the Core Motion framework to get gyro data directly. With this, you can track the exact current direction the device is facing in 3D space.

```
_motionManager = [CMMotionManager new];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

[_motionManager setGyroUpdateInterval:1.0/20.0];
[_motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",gyroData);
}];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i had achieved this detection though raw values previously and i have mentioned this in my question too the problem is to detect the whole motion of flipping from isFaceUp to isFaceDown

Comment: okey that should be more accurate but i still don't see how it will detect the motion , it detects two end positions very accurately but i am not sure how will i know my user has flipped his device

Comment: the problem is not of accuracy to detect the end position but the logic to detect this whole motion

Comment: this gives me lots of gyroData for trajectory of flip by the user which is not in my control so still i wont be able to define , yes the flip has happened , is there an algorithm or logic i can apply here.

Comment: BTW i was detecting these raw values before i asked the question by using UIAccelerometer data and using its application delegate to get x,y and z values of accelerometer in -(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration